# Should / how to put Q&A site participation on resume?

Tags: resume

I'm applying to Software Engineer jobs. I've been an relatively active user on Stack Overflow, Software Engineering Stack Exchange, and the Rust language user forums for a number of years, with relatively high quantitative metrics as well as a history of well-liked questions and answers to show for it on both. I'm wondering if this is worth putting on my resume, and, if so, how best to include it? Thanks.

Comment: Interesting first question. Do you think your 1500 rep on SO is worth anything on the job market?

Comment: @Kilisi I'm not sure, and I'm open to answers which just say I shouldn't. If it is valuable it would be as evidence that I can explain things well.

Comment: A small score isn't going to impress. Even a high score is minimally impressive. "Active and respected member of community for the past decade, specializing in answers about... "  might. "Moderator for past decade" more so.. Still more a personality statement than n a skills statement, though moderator may be evidence of soft skills. Active and respected participant/committer in an open-source project might draw more interest, but I'd still put it in the personal-interedts category unless you were a seriously major mover in something that has wide uptake and is considered important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I can think is, to put it under your hobbies and interests. Do not add too much information, mention your involvement, and a link to the profile should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Being an active contributor on the Stack Overflow, Software Engineering Stack Exchange, and Rust user forums can certainly be a valuable addition to your resume, especially if you're applying for a software engineering job. Putting this on your resume can demonstrate your passion for technology, ability to communicate and collaborate effectively, and commitment to continuous learning and development - and can make you stand out from other applicants..

I think you can create a separate section titled (for example) "Community Contributions" where you can list relevant platforms and your contributions. For example, list 2-3 tags where you help the most, e.g. "StackOverflow, Rust tag - 50 answers and 1,000 reputation points"

Remember to primarily emphasize your relevant work experience and technical skills. Community contributions as an additional way to showcase your knowledge, communication skills and passion for technology.